# Word or phrase to describe the lack of something - especially action

Tags: expressions

Is there a word or phrase in the English language that describes "something that should be done, but is not being done?" 
examples:

- The absence of help when an old lady obviously needs it. Is there a general term for the help that should be there?
- There is a piece of garbage on the floor/road. Is there a general term for the cleaning that should be done?
- There is a beautiful flower that should be seen. Is there a general term for the viewing that is not happening.
- There is a murderous monster on the loose, but no one is doing anything about it. Is there a general term for the missing action?

Is there a general term/phrase that could describe all examples above?

Comment: Not really. The first two could be described as _unmet needs_.

Comment: According to [The Law Dictionary](https://dictionary.thelaw.com/willful-negligence/), **willful negligence** is 'Negligence where there is a wanton disregard of the risks concerning the circumstances and the actor is aware of  [but] disregards these significant risks'. But it would take the best judge ever to decide where culpability lies, and the extent of such. Not many sell all they have and give to the poor in a considered way.